# What is the best way to run unit/integration tests on a MySQL database?

Tags: python, mysql, pytest

I'm writing what I call unit tests (but are probably integration tests) for a series of functions in a script that mainly execute insert/delete/update queries on a MySQL database using SQLAlchemy.

Currently my tests run as follows:

- Spin up a test schema
- Use a for loop to populate the test schema from a spreadsheet that has a sheet for each table (using `read_excel` and `to_sql` from pandas)
- Run the test function
- Query the schema to get a test result dataframe using `read_sql` from pandas
- Compare the test result to an expected result using `assert_frame_equal` (the expected result is also extracted from a sheet in the Excel file)

This seems to be overly complicated and I'm sure I'm not the only person running tests on MySQL. Is there a better way?

I've considered creating MySQL dump files for every test but this seems like a lot of effort - they aren't as quick to build as Excel files...

Comment: Would you consider using SQLite in [:memory:](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html?highlight=sqlite3#module-sqlite3) mode for your unit tests?

Comment: Hi @BalajiAmbresh. Everything I’d read said to try to replicate the db you’re using if at all possible so I’d stuck with MySQL

Comment: Got it. As mentioned by @yg-dba, jest is a nice choice.

Answer (score 1):

We've had a lot of success using jest to run integration tests on the DAL service logic that calls the database.  We create a parallel database where we run migrations, and truncate all the tables after each test.

Here is a link:
https://walrus.ai/blog/2020/04/testing-database-interactions-with-jest/

To use Jest with Python:
https://jest-community.github.io/jest-pytest/

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I’m new to programming so would prefer to try to stick with python at this stage

Comment: I added info about the Python support for jest.

Comment: Thanks - there's not much documentation on ```jest_pytest``` and I'm only starting out with coding. Probably a bit beyond me at this stage!

Comment: K.  Wishing you lots of success in figuring it out!  It definitely gets challenging when learning new technologies